# picaxe 28x1 random number generator

Tags: random, picaxe

I have some simple code using the random number function from picaxes website (slightly adapted)

```
symbol counter = b7
symbol randword = b5
for counter = 0 to 10

let randword = timer
random randword

write counter, b5
next counter

end
```

For some reason on picaxe editor version 5 this works perfectly but on picaxe editor 6 all it does is give out 2's, not very random, I have no idea why.

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this in simulation or on a real PICAXE?

Comment: simulation and PICAXE for editor 6 and just simulation for editor 5 at the moment.

Comment: Also, I've added a wait loop which requires you to press a button to start the program so the running time should be random

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [PICAXE BASIC language manual](http://www.picaxe.com/docs/picaxe_manual2.pdf) shows a few possible problems with your code:

- the `timer` system variable has to be initialised with the `settimer` command before you can use it
- depending on what preload value you use with `settimer`, the value of `timer` may well not have changed in the short time between one loop iteration and the next, which will give you the same result from `random`
- `random` should be used with a word variable (w0, w1, etc) not a byte variable

What I think the manual entry for `random` is suggesting you should do, although I agree it isn't exactly clear if you're new to random number generation, is to seed `random` with `timer` the **first** time you call it, then seed it with its own previous value each time after that:

```
symbol counter = b5

let w3 = timer         ; w3 is the word variable consisting of b6 and b7
for counter = 0 to 10

random w3
;  ...do something with the value of w3 (but don't change w3 itself)...

next counter
```

**However** after saying all this, it is certainly possible that the simulator in one or other version of the PICAXE Programming Editor doesn't simulate the behaviour of `timer` correctly in all cases. If you can't get the code working on a real PICAXE, take this question to the [PICAXE forum](http://www.picaxeforum.co.uk/forum.php) where it will be seen by Revolution Education support staff as well as other knowledgeable users.